# Por que que os SGBDs utilizam a sua própria paginação se o sistema operacional já possui uma?

Tags: sistema-operacional, banco-de-dados

Estou estudando banco de dados e acabei chegando ao assunto de substituição de páginas como LRU e MRU. O sistema operacional já faz isso normalmente, por que o DB precisa fazer a sua própria paginação?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Porque os objetivos são diferentes. O sistema operacional cria páginas de bytes, o banco de dados cria páginas de dados com propósito específico. Ele sabe melhor o que tem ali dentro, as páginas dele possuem um formato específico, tanto que é comum que nem todas páginas são iguais, cada tipo de página possui uma estrutura de dados específica. Ele precisa ter mais controle de como elas são manipuladas. Em geral é otimizado para a performance.

O OS costuma usar uma lista ligada não muito eficiente para o padrão de acesso do banco de dados.

- Claro que a não ser que o DB passe for cima da *filesystem* (era comum, hoje não é mais), ele também usa a paginação do OS em um nível mais baixo. Uma página do DB pode ocupar várias páginas do OS ou uma página do OS pode conter várias páginas do DB, isto depende do que é melhor para cada situação.

  Tem bancos que usam a paginação do OS primariamente. Os que optaram por ter uma paginação própria precisavam de um nível extra de controle do que está memória. Tem um algoritmo de substituição mais apropriado ([MRU, LRU, LRU-k, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms)). O algoritmo do banco de dados sabe o que deve estar ativo e pode priorizar o que é mais importante para aquele caso (índices, especialmente primários, precisam estar disponíveis com prioridade). Lembrando que a paginação do OS continua sendo usada para compor as páginas do DB.

  Em geral as páginas do disco batem com as páginas da memória no caso do DB. Como elas podem ser de tamanhos diferentes do que é usado no OS (para se adequar ao padrão de acesso), faz todo sentido ter um controle próprio.

  Existem bancos que preferem deixar o cache de páginas totalmente por conta do OS, outros usam os dois níveis. Isso pode até dificultar a otimização do consumo de memória, já que o dado está em dois locais diferentes, mas pode dar mais segurança e flexibilidade.
- Dependendo da implementação do DB não é possível ficar manipulando direto nas páginas do OS. Nem sempre é necessário manipular os dados que o OS pode jogar em disco. Cada implementação tem sua especificidade e vai manipular do jeito que lhe for mais adequado. O DB precisa decidir por conta própria o que deve ir para o "disco" ou não.
- Com um algoritmo mais especializado é possível obter mais performance e escalabilidade, além de mais flexibilidade e confiabilidade.
- Com um sistema próprio é possível abstrair as condições dos diversos sistemas operacionais. E pode se adaptar quando uma condição não atende mais as expectativas e necessidades.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).