# O que é uma lista encadeada?

Tags: terminologia, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Estive lendo alguns materiais e vi muito se falar em listas encadeadas. Até vi o exemplo de código (em C) abaixo que tentava "ilustrar" o que era uma.

```c
struct Node
{
    int info;
    struct Node *proximo;
};
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é:

- O que é um lista encadeada?
- Em que momento ela é realmente útil?

<sub>Como minha linguagem principal é C#, apreciaria algum exemplo usando-a, mas isto não é crucial.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boa parte já está respondida em [Qual a diferença entre lista simplesmente-encadeada e duplamente-encadeada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102983/101).

Então lista encadeada é o mesmo que lista ligada (*linked list*).

O funcionamento da lista encadeada é através de nós independentes onde está o elemento. Cada elemento possui pelo menos um ponteiro/referência indicando onde está o próximo nó. Na lista duplamente encadeada tem um ponteiro indicando o nó anterior também. Justamente por isso só se sabe onde está cada nó se souber onde está o anterior (ou o próximo), ela só pode ser acessada sequencialmente. Mas por serem nós independentes fica fácil colocar o que deseja onde deseja no meio da lista.

## Utilidade

Ela é útil quando precisa manipular seus elementos internamente, ou seja, precisa incluir e/ou remover itens no meio da lista de forma simples. Mas precisa ter que fazer isso com muita frequência, se for baixa, não costuma compensar (sempre tem exceção). A sua principal característica é ser O(1) para essas operações. Mas tem O(n) para acesso que é a operação mais usada na maioria das situações. Então ela é bem pouco usada.

Ela tem a vantagem de ter seus elementos espalhados, e por isso é fácil manipular a lista, mas tem o problema de não ser uma sequência contígua, então não pode acessar aleatoriamente, para chegar no elemento precisa fazer uma busca sequencial. Isso ainda tem o problema que não é *cache friendly* e o processador pode ter que trabalhar mais para acessar os elementos.

Na verdade em boa parte dos casos onde há necessidade de manipulação interna da lista, é mais interessante o uso de uma árvore, talvez binária, que permite inserir e remover elementos em O(log n) e acessar os elementos em O(log n). A complexidade O(log n) é muito próxima de O(1). Por isso hoje ela é uma estrutura muito pouco usada, são raros os problemas onde precisa manipular internamente e o acesso só precisa ser sequencial. Em alguns casos [Radix pode ser mais útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111202/101).

Um erro comum é achar que a inserção e remoção pode ocorrer em O(1) sempre. A operação isoladamente sempre pode ocorrer em O(1), mas você precisa estar no nó que deseja inserir ou remover, caso contrário terá um O(n) adicional até chegar nele.

[Veja sobre Big O](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101). Lembrando que essas medidas são sempre o pior caso. Em lista ligada o caso médio é O(n/2) e o melhor caso O(1), se for o primeiro (último) item.

## Exemplos

É muito comum as linguagens possuírem uma implementação de lista encadeada em sua biblioteca padrão. Em C# em geral não precisa nem fazer uma, já existe a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0) ([veja o código fonte](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,df5a6c7b6b60da4f)) que atende bem quase todas situações. Só vejo motivo alguém fazer por conta própria se estiver estudando o assunto, se precisa de algo muito específico (bem raro), por exemplo se acha que o custo da lista ter dois ponteiros é alto de mais para usá-la, aí uma lista simplesmente ligada pode ser mais útil (raro).

Existe ainda o uso da [lista encadeada circular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circularly_linked_vs._linearly_linked), mas é bem raro precisar. Ela não tem início ou fim, quando chega ao fim, ela já aponta pra o início. Esse *link* da Wikipedia tem uma descrição mais detalhada sobre todo o assunto.

Um [exemplo prático é a *filesystem*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103418/101) (portando nada tem a ver com RAM) e o [gerenciamento da memória virtual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98315/101).

Uma implementação simples e bem ingênua e sem ser [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), faltam muitos métodos que podem ser úteis:

```cs
using static System.Console;

public class Node<T> {
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
}

public class LinkedList<T> {
    private Node<T> head = null;

    public Node<T> Add(T value) {
        var node = new Node<T> {Value = value};
        if (head == null) head = node;
        else {
            var current = head;
            while (current.Next != null) current = current.Next;
            current.Next = node;
        }
        return node;
    }

    public T Remove(Node<T> node) {
        if (head == null) return node.Value;
        if (head == node) {
            head = head.Next;
            node.Next = null;
            return node.Value;
        }
        var current = head;
        while (current.Next != null) {
            if (current.Next == node) {
                current.Next = node.Next;
                return node.Value;
            }
            current = current.Next;
        }
        return node.Value;
    }

    public void Print() {
        var current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            WriteLine(current.Value);
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var ll = new LinkedList<int>();
        var node1 = ll.Add(1);
        var node2 = ll.Add(2);
        var node3 = ll.Add(3);
        var node4 = ll.Add(4);
        var node5 = ll.Add(5);
        ll.Print();
        WriteLine();
        ll.Remove(node3);
        ll.Print();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kewK86). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X6kD4V). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/MyLinkedList.cs).

Answer (score 5):

**O que é**

Pense em uma sequência de objetos do mesmo tipo, onde cada elementos é armazenado em uma lista. O primeiro elemento na primeira célula, o segundo na segunda e assim por diante. A [lista encadeada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_ligada) é a representação dessa sequência. Ela oferece os procedimentos básicos para manipulação dos dados: inserção, remoção e busca. O seu caráter dinâmico é umas das características mais importantes da lista encadeada, pois permite armazenar um número de elementos limitado apenas pela memória disponível.

**Utilidade**

As listas encadeadas são úteis quando você não sabe quantos itens estarão na lista, quando você não precisa de acesso aleatório a qualquer elemento, quando você quer inserir itens no meio da lista  e também quando precisa de inserções/exclusões constantes.

As vantagens de se usar uma lista encadeada é que a inserção ou remoção de um elemento na lista não implica a mudança de lugar de outros elementos e não é necessário definir, no momento da criação da lista, o número máximo de elementos que esta poderá ter. Ou seja, é possível alocar memória "dinamicamente", apenas para o número de nós necessários.

Uma manipulação torna-se mais "perigosa" uma vez que, se o encadeamento (ligação) entre elementos da lista for mal feito, toda a lista pode ser perdida, fazendo com que isso seja uma desvantagens do uso da lista encadeada. Uma outra desvantagem é que para ter acesso ao elemento na posição `n` da lista, deve-se percorrer os `n - 1` anteriores.

**Exemplo**

Código em C#, retirado desse [site](https://murilocurti.wordpress.com/2004/11/03/estruturas-de-dados-em-c-part-1-lista-simplesmente-encadeada/).

Com essa implementação podem ser executados todos os  procedimentos básicos para manipulação dos dados (inserção, remoção e busca). Nesse código a classe `Node` contém o campo `Info`, para receber um objeto, e `Next`, para referenciar o próximo objeto da nossa lista. A classe `Nodes` é uma coleção de objetos `Node`, que é útil para percorrer a lista toda. Nas Classes `Node` e `Nodes` conseguimos armazenar `n` objetos em forma de uma lista sequencial sem um limite. Com esse algoritmo otimizado pode-se simplificar o trabalho e diminuir `overloads` nas aplicações para realizar determinadas tarefas.

```
public class Node
{
   public Node(object info, Node next)
   {
      this.Info = info;
      Next = next;
   }

   public Node(object info)
   {
        Info = info;
        Next = null;
   }

   public object Info = null;
   public Node Next = null;
}

public class Nodes : CollectionBase
{
   public Node this[int item]
   {get{return this.GetNode(item);}}

   public void Add(Node node)
   {
         List.Add(node);
   }

   public bool Remove(int index)
   {
        if (index > Count – 1 || index < 0)
           return false;
        else
       {
          List.RemoveAt(index);
          return true;
        }
    }

   private Node GetNode(int Index)
   {
      return (Node) List[Index];
   }

}


public class ListaSimples
{
   private Node Node;

   public void InsereInicio(object info)
   {
         if(Node == null)
            Node = new Node(info);
         else
            Node = new Node(info,Node);
   }

   public Node RemoveInicio()
   {
         Node no = null;
         if(Node != null)
         {
             no = Node;
             Node = Node.Next;
         }
         return no;
   }

   public void InsereFinal(object info)
   {
         if(Node == null)
            Node = new Node(info);
         else
         {
             Node nodeAux = Node;
             while(nodeAux.Next != null)
             {
                nodeAux = nodeAux.Next;
             }
             nodeAux.Next = new Node(info);
          }
   }

   public Node RemoveFinal()
   {
         Node no = null;
         Node nodeAux;
         Node nodeAux2 = new Node(null);
         if(Node != null)
         {
             nodeAux = Node;
             while(nodeAux.Next != null)
             {
                 nodeAux2 = nodeAux;
                 nodeAux = nodeAux.Next;
              }

              no = nodeAux;
              nodeAux = null;
              nodeAux2.Next = null;
           }
           return no;
   }

   public Nodes Percorre()
   {
          Node nodeAux = Node;
          Nodes nodes = new Nodes();
          while(nodeAux != null)
          {
              nodes.Add(nodeAux);
              nodeAux = nodeAux.Next;
          }
          return nodes;
   }

   public bool Busca(object info)
   {
         bool exists = false;
         if(Node != null)
         {
             Node nodeAux = Node;
             while(nodeAux != null)
             {
                 if(nodeAux.Info == info)
                 {
                     exists = true;
                     break;
                  }
                  nodeAux = nodeAux.Next;
               }
          }
          return exists;
   }

   public void Clear()
   {
        Node = null;
   }

}
```

Referências:

- [Listas encadeadas - IME](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/lista.html)
- [Lista encadeadas - Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_ligada)
- [Estrutura de dados em C#](https://murilocurti.wordpress.com/2004/11/03/estruturas-de-dados-em-c-part-1-lista-simplesmente-encadeada/)