# O que é cabeça da lista encadeada?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada

Não entendi o que cabeça ou (*head*) da lista significa, e qual a vantagem em utilizar ela?

Comment: http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/10/Lista-simplesmente-encadeada-com-cabeca-em-C-Inserindo-nos-no-inicio-e-fim.html

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é uma lista encadeada?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/o-que-%c3%a9-uma-lista-encadeada)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É o endereço inicial da lista, é o primeiro elemento que é necessário saber por onde começar a andar por ela. Essa informação precisa estar na estrutura de dados (a instância da lista). Depois a localização dos demais elementos vai achando nos próprios elementos, já que a lista ligada tem como característica justamente ter nós com o valor e o próximo elemento.

Se a lista for duplamente encadeada precisa também um `tail` para começar ao contrário. É comum ter o `tail`, mesmo em lista simplesmente encadeadas como otimização para facilitar a inserção no final da lista sem precisar percorrê-la toda.

De uma certa forma pense que ele é um dos nós que não tem valor e que já está enclausurada dentro da estrutura da lista. Tanto que em muitos casos o `head` é apenas um nó e nada mais e ele se confunde com a própria lista. Lembrando que o final é um nós que não possui um apontador para o próximo elemento.

Não é possível fazer a lista ligada sem uma cabeça. Se não tivesse, começaria por onde? O que pode fazer é a cabeça ser a própria lista. Se não precisar de informações adicionais para controlar a lista ligada, e em casos simples não precisa mesmo, então guarde um nó na variável que vai conter a sua lista, este nó é a cabeça. A cabeça não precisa necessariamente ter um tratamento especial em casos simples, mas precisa existir um lugar que comece a lista.

Algo assim funciona se não precisa de uma lista complexa:

```
typedef struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
if (head == NULL) {
    return 1;
}
head->value = 1;
head->next = NULL;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/LinkedList.c).

Neste caso só está apontando para `NULL` porque além de ser o primeiro elemento é também o último. Assim que inserir um novo elemento, o endereço do novo será colocado em `head->next`, substituindo o `NULL`, assim como fará em todos os outros elementos. Esse é o funcionamento básico de uma lista ligada.

[Mais informações sobre lista ligada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164085/101).