# O que seria o next desse código?

Tags: java, lista-encadeada

Estou fazendo alguns exercícios para treina Java e me caiu esta questão:

> Given the head of a singly linked list, return the middle node of the
> linked list. If there are two middle nodes, return the second middle
> node.

```
 public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 }
```

> Input: head = [1,2,3,4,5]
>
> Output: [3,4,5]
>
> Explanation: The middle node of the list is node 3.

Fiquei algum tempo e não consegui fazer, fui ver a resposta para descobrir no que estava errando e me apareceu esta reposta:

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode middleNode(ListNode head) {
        ListNode slow = head;
        ListNode fast = head.next;
        while (fast != null) {
            slow = slow.next;
            if (fast.next == null) {
                fast = fast.next;
            } else {
                fast = fast.next.next;
            }
        }
        return slow;
    }
}
```

Esse `next`, ele é um método do Java? Ou um atributo da `class ListNode?` ou os dois? Só quero entender melhor o código para consegui pega a logica.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Não é um método de Java, até porque métodos possuem `()` logo após o nome (existem situações que isto pode não ocorrer, mas não é o caso), e este não possui. Não tem como algo ser duas coisas tão distintas ao mesmo tempo.

Ele não é um atributo porque esse é o termo que [quase todo mundo aprende errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). Mas é um campo da classe `ListNode`, isto está bem claro no código no segundo campo.

Como isso é uma [lista ligada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164085/101), cada nó tem um valor e onde está o próximo nó, por isso ela é ligada. Veja na ilustração abaixo que o `next` está representado aqui por uma bolinha onde teria o endereço do objeto que tem o próximo nó (é a melhor representação gráfica para um [ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101)):

[image: Objetos ligados por setas fazendo a ligação]

Note que o tipo de `next` é o tipo da classe, ou seja, ali vai guardar uma referência para um objeto igual a este que ele pertence, porque esta é a característica deste tipo de lista que não vou explicar já que tem *links* que já o fazem. O construtor mais completo mostra a atribuição do objeto do mesmo tipo em `next`.

Como em todos os nós o campo existe, você pode acessá-lo em qualquer circunstância, até mesmo pode acessar o `next` que indica um objeto que tem um `next`, por isso tem o código `fast.next.next` que pega o próximo nó que está sendo indicado no próximo nó indicado por `fast`.

Lembrando que se o nó tem valor `null` ele é o último da lista, ou seja, não tem um próximo nó. Então precisaria do devido tratamento aí.

Veja também: [O que é cabeça da lista encadeada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170420/101).

Comment: Nossa muito obg pela explicação e pelos links, me ajudou muito mesmo.

Comment: @Alan veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado, ou seja, marcando a resposta como correta no verdinho ali do lado esquerdo abaixo das setas dos votos, que você logo poderá dar também.