# As configurações de hardware são relevantes para a medição da eficiência dos algoritmos de ordenação?

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo

Eu estava lendo um artigo no [DevMedia](http://www.devmedia.com.br/algoritmos-de-ordenacao-analise-e-comparacao/28261) sobre os principais algoritmos de ordenação.

No artigo são comparados quatro algoritmos desse tipo, [bubble sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), [selection sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort), [quick sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) e [insertion sort](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Bem, pensei que o hardware não fosse relevante para comparar algoritmos entre si, porque, pelo meu raciocínio, eles estariam sendo testados no mesmo computador, porém, li sobre [branch prediction](http://igoro.com/archive/fast-and-slow-if-statements-branch-prediction-in-modern-processors/), logo depois, então a dúvida surgiu: **o hardware é importante para medir comparativamente algoritmos de ordenação?**

Mas, acho que a pergunta seria melhor respondida se eu soubesse a resposta para a origem da dúvida: **as diferentes CPUs (sigla em inglês para Unidade Central de Processamento) podem implementar branch prediction de tal forma que o algoritmo *A* seja mais eficiente que o algoritmo *B* em uma CPU e menos eficiente em outra?**

Comment: O processador é tão complexo que ninguém nem deve saber esta resposta, somente testando mesmo. Porém estes algoritmos de ordenação são tão diferentes que é altamente improvável que o hardware influencie no resultado de comparação que você está tentando medir. O importante é usar o mesmo hardware para medição.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há controvérsias. Isso [pode ser visto nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33319/101). Leia tudo, inclusive os comentários, tem coisa muito boa ali, inclusive mostrando como as coisas ocorrem de fato na prática.

Me parece que entende que medir a complexidade de algoritmo não é medir a velocidade dele. Há uma relação entre ambos, mas não é tão direta assim.

É claro que é impossível pegar muitos dados e ter um O(n^m) mais rápido que um O(1) em qualquer hardware.

O algoritmo, da maneira como as pessoas fazem, não leva em consideração condições de hardware.

O mais comum é classificar a eficiência dentro de um ambiente neutro. Em geral não considera-se otimizações.

Imagine rodar isso em um computador sobrecarregado. Toda teoria evapora. Imagina um computador que gasta mais tempo fazendo *swap* em disco do que no cálculo. De que adianta saber na teoria qual a eficiência do algoritmo?

Na teoria pode-se considerar o hardware. Pode-se adicionar variáveis que considere essas condições. Mas é muito raro ter vantagem em saber isso. Em geral isso é feito em ambiente acadêmico ou de análise muito específica e quando está se fazendo algo que terá muita utilização em algo que potencialmente precisa de muita performance. Então há casos para considerar todas variáveis. No dia a dia você faz uma análise de eficiência superficial para escolher o algoritmo correto e faz testes reais de velocidade com dados típicos e extremos para ver o que acontece de fato em condições reais. Costuma dar resultados mais adequados do ponto de vista de engenharia, ainda que do ponto de vista científico não seja necessariamente o melhor.

Eu já vi gente dizendo que existem cálculos nesse sentido, mas nunca vi alguém os mostrando. Eu sei que eles existem, mas estão bem escondidos :)

Dito tudo isso, a minha experiência mostra que cache faz mais diferença do que *branch prediction* na maioria dos casos. Algoritmos que possuem menos *branches* podem ser mais eficientes em máquinas mais simples.

Um algoritmo que deve manipular dados em disco pode ser o mais adequado, enquanto que os mesmo dados em memória outro algoritmo pode ser mais adequado. Imagine que um cache L1 ou até mesmo registradores pudessem comportar todos os dados a serem processados como poderia haver melhoria.

Lembrando que para poucos dados (N baixo), na prática, tanto faz qual o algoritmo usado.

Veja isto [Algoritmos de ordenação de memória externa e interna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166229/101).